# Can you Serialize inside a set of Attributes by Set of Attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want a serialize a set of attributes all together to an XML file in a loop that runs. This loop runs within a set of folders . According to my Current implementation  It only shows the last set of Attributes.

Here is my Current code ,

```
Student  obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < StudentModel  (File.ReadAllText(file));



string Name = studentModel.name;
string number = studentModel.number;

string testPath = rootDirectory;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentModel));
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(testPath + "\\Test.xml");
serializer.Serialize(writer, studentModel);
writer.Close();
```

My Current output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<name>Max</name>
<number>1</number>

</StudentModel>
```

Required output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<name>Max</name>
<number>1</number>

</StudentModel>

<StudentModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<name>Amy</name>
<number>2</number>

</StudentModel>

<StudentModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<name>Jack</name>
<number>3</number>

</StudentModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that what you want to do is serialize a list (or array) of `StudentModel` to an xml. Currently you are only serializing one instance of `StudentModel` and overwrite the resulting xml each iteration of the loop, leaving you with the last item. What you can do, is to create a class with a `List()` of `StudentModel` as Property and serialize that class instance, not needing a loop anymore.

The List property in your new class would then look something like this:

```
[XmlArray("StudentModels"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(StudentModel), ElementName = "StudentModel")] 
public List<StudentModel> StudentModelList{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I believe this will work @Roland Deschain . Appreciate the help

Comment: Glad I could help :)